# How to use multiple if statements inside append() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am returning a json response from the server. In the JSON response keys will have value eiether "**yes**" or empty value **""**. With laravel i can generate using blade if statements. Since it is a json response i don't know how to append this json values i get inside a html elements. Depends on the json value the design of the elements changes

```
@if($candidate->priority == "")

    @if($candidate->fav == "")
        <a class = "favorite" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" > <img id = "no_p_fav" src="{{url('/icons/non_star.png')}}" ></img></a>
    @else if($candidate->priority == "yes")
        <a class = "favorite" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}"><img id = "no_p_fav" src="{{url('/icons/star.png')}}"></img></a>
    @endif

 @elseif($candidate->priority == "yes")
    @if($candidate->fav == "")
        <a class = "favorite" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" > <img id = "fav" src="{{url('/icons/non_star.png')}}" ></img></a>
    @else if($candidate->priority == "yes")
        <a class = "favorite" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}"><img id = "fav" src="{{url('/icons/star.png')}}"></img></a>
    @endif
    @endif

    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><img id = "menu" src="{{url('/icons/menu.png')}}"></img></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
            @if($candidate->priority == "")
            <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prioritize</li></a><br>
            @elseif($candidate->priority == "yes")
            <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Deprioritize</li></a><br>
            @endif
```

I know if its checking only one condition i can use ternary operators to check and append. I don't know how to append in this case. If i check the conditions before and append accordingly, then i will get to append more or less same code for 4 times(cuz no of conditions). How do  check the conditions and append them here.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript and jQuery? Laravel is in PHP.

Comment: The code `@if` and `@endif` are laravel blade engine codes. Just for information purpose i said that